# Hov can get the translated values in select?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I get `select` with values `Without` and `With`. How can I get already translated values `Без` and `С` in `django.po` in a `select`?

**models.py**

```
CONFIRMATION_WITHOUT = 'without'
CONFIRMATION_OTHER = 'other'
CONFIRMATION_WITH = 'with'

CONFIRMATION_CHOICES = (
    (CONFIRMATION_WITHOUT, _('Without')),         #Без
    (CONFIRMATION_OTHER, _('Other')),             #Другое
    (CONFIRMATION_WITH, _('With')),               #С
)

income_proof = models.CharField(_('proof'), max_length=255, choices=CONFIRMATION_CHOICES, default=CONFIRMATION_WITHOUT)
#[u'without', u'with']
```

**forms.py**

```
income_proof = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CreditPayment.objects.values_list('income_proof', flat=True).distinct(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'selectpicker form-control', 'title':_("Income proof")}))
```

**html**

```
{{ form.income_proof }}
```

It is possible to make in the form, for example?

```
<select>
    <option value = "CONFIRMATION_WITHOUT">Без</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You should work with lazy translation objects: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#working-with-lazy-translation-objects.

Comment: Thank. In my case, _ this is ugettext_lazy. But for some reason, the translation is not displayed in this select ...

Comment: are you sure you have "activated" the language (correctly)?

Comment: Yes. In admin page all data are translated. I'm updated my ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the form, you should *not* use a [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField). Indeed, you here do *not* select a model object, but a value. You thus should use a [**`ChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField) instead.

As for the options, I think you want to use `CONFIRMATION_CHOICES`, since by using a queryset, you query the database, and you thus are only able to pick `income_proof`s that are already picked by *other* records.

```
from app.models import CONFIRMATION_CHOICES
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    income_proof = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=CONFIRMATION_CHOICES,
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={'class': 'selectpicker form-control', 'title':_('Income proof')}
        )
    )
```

or if you only want the values that were selected, you can use:

```
from app.models import CONFIRMATION_CHOICES
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    income_proof = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[],
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={'class': 'selectpicker form-control', 'title':_('Income proof')}
        )
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        render = dict(CONFIRMATION_CHOICES)
        self.fields['income_proof'].choices = [
            (k, render.get(k, k))
            for k in CreditPayment.objects.values_list('income_proof', flat=True).distinct()
        ]
```

Here the `__init__` is called when we construct the form. We first let the super constructor do the work to create the fields, then make a dictionary of the `CONFIRMATION_CHOICES`.

Next, we perform a query (the same one you used) to get the database values for `income_proof`, and we use the dictionary to map these to the corresponding translations. We thus yield a list of 2-tuples as choices for that form field.

We here thus use the [**`choices=`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices) which should contain:

> **`choices`**
>
> Either an iterable of 2-tuples to use as choices for this field, or a
>   callable that returns such an iterable. This argument accepts the same
>   formats as the `choices` argument to a model field. See the model
>   field reference documentation on choices for more details. If the
>   argument is a callable, it is evaluated each time the field's form is
>   initialized. Defaults to an empty list.

Comment: You did not understand why I used ModelChoiceField. See it. There is a list of fields for select in admin panel (1, 2, 3). There are 2 records. In one, the value 1 is selected, in the second - 3. Therefore, I need to render in a user form (NOT IN ADMIN) in the select values 1 and 3. If I do as you say, ALL values will be drawn.

Comment: @pythoner: in that case, I think you can set the choices in the `__init__` field, by looking up their corresponding translation, like in the edited answer. But a `ModelChoiceField` should only be used if the *elements* in the field are model objects.

Comment: Very thnx. I had a wrong idea about `ModelChoiceField`.

Comment: @pythoner: `__init__` is called when we construct the form. We first let the super class do the work to create the fields, then make a dictionary of the `CONFIRMATION_CHOICES`, then use a query (the same one you used) to get the database values for `income_proof`, and we usee the dictionary to map these to the corresponding translations. We thus yield a list of 2-tuples as choices for that form field.

Comment: Interesting conversion of tuples into a dictionary. I have not seen this before.